# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj'

Tags: django, django-settings, modulenotfounderror, python-importlib, django-deployment

I ran into this problem and searched many resources but couldn't find a solution. My Django project was running successfully on my local. But when I deployed it to the server, it kept getting the following error.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj'

I installed all the required libraries and all the settings should be correct as they worked fine on my OSX.

```
(venv) [root@10-10-7-140 vanilla]# python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/python3.8/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 427, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/data/www/vanilla/vanilla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/python3.8/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj'
```

I noticed the message of `if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:` and checked my code in venilla/settings.py, which includes:

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Furthermore, the following line is standard in my manage.py.

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'vanilla.settings')
```

I checked all the libraries are installed correctly, tried to run
`python manage.py makemigrations` and
`python manage.py check`. Got the same error.

Really wondering what caused my problem. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the system, I found the following line in `/etc/profile`.

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=proj.settings
```

It seta the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `proj.settings` and cannot be overwritten by `manage.py`. After removing it and rebooting the system, the problem is resolved.